# Changing column name (case sensitive identifiers) in Azure Synapse -SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

I am trying to change the column name from AccountId to AccountID. I am using the following stroed procedure:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'schema.Account.AccountId', 'AccountID', 'COLUMN';
```

and I get the following error message:

> Msg 112012, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
> Parameter newname: 'AccountID' is invalid. sp_rename cannot rename column 'AccountId' to 'AccountID' because column 'AccountID' already exists in the table.

My understanding is that the column name (identifier) is case insensitive and this is preventing sp_rename to change the column name.

Ideally I'd like to just change the column name to be case sensitive (or find a way to change the column name) vs having to recreate the table on a temp table, copy all the data, dependencies, references to the table etc.

For more reference the data in the column I'm trying to change are of int data type.

I also tried to use sp_rename to change to Account_id_old and then sp_rename to Account_ID and that worked on my dev environment but when I tried to merge the schema changes to prod it bombed since these tables/columns are referenced on other user defined stored procedures that I am trying not to have to modify.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given your system clearly isn't case sensitive, why do you care?

Comment: What do you mean "it bombed"? What exact and specific error messages did you get? It seems, at least in your dev environment, that you have a case-insensitive default database collation so none of your referencing tables, views, functions or procedures should care if the column is named `AccountId` or `AccountID`. Where it could matter is "client-side" ORMs if they're trying to use case-sensitive column-property mapping strategies.

Comment: Do a two-step change from AccountId to AccountIDTemp to AccountID

Comment: The [sp_rename doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#examples-) states it's currently supported in Azure Synapse Analytics only for objects in the dbo schema.

Comment: @DaleK just to do some house keeping and for consistency.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the build failed when I did the two-step process that siggemannen suggested (AccountId_old to AccountID on a post deployment script) because the columns I am trying to change names to on the post deployment script are referenced on a bunch of stored procedures so when these see a column name "AccountId_old" the build fails. I will pull the error messages I am getting and post them shortly.

Answer (score 0):

My understaind is this error prevents the accidental overwriting of existing columns and maintains integrity of the table's structure.

The error occurs because the sp_rename stored procedure is used to rename a column, but the new name specified ("AccountID") is already an existing column in the table ("AccountID"). The sp_rename procedure doesn't allow renaming a column to a name that already exists in the table.

For example I have Created a table.

```
CREATE  TABLE MyTable
(
accountid INT,
Name VARCHAR(50),
Balance DECIMAL(10, 2)
)
```

I have encountred the same error like you have

[image]

I have recreated the stored procedure that will rename my Column name with Case sensitive. like below.

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE dbo.RenameColumns
AS
BEGIN
IF  OBJECT_ID('MyTable', 'U') IS  NOT  NULL
BEGIN
IF  EXISTS (
SELECT  1
FROM sys.columns
WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyTable')
AND name = 'AccountId'
)
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'EXEC sp_rename ''MyTable."AccountId"'', ''Account_ID_Renamed'', ''COLUMN'';';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Column AccountId does not exist in MyTable.', 16, 1);
END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Table MyTable does not exist.', 16, 1);
END
END
```

[image]
In this stored Proc checks if a table named "MyTable" exists in the current database. The 'U' parameter specifies that it should check for user-defined tables.
`IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyTable') AND name = 'AccountId')` This  checks if a column named **"AccountId"** exists in the **"MyTable"** table.

It queries the sys.columns system catalog view to find the column based on the object_id of the table and the column name.

```
SET @sql = N'EXEC sp_rename ''MyTable."AccountId"'', ''Account_ID_Renamed'', ''COLUMN''
```

The Renaming is happening here
rename the column "**AccountId"** to **"Account_ID_Renamed"** in the "**MyTable**"

**`RAISERROR('Table MyTable does not exist.', 16, 1)`**: This line raises an error with the specified message if the "MyTable" table does not exist.
[image]
Here Is the other way you can create a New table with new Column name using the stored Procedure that does the New table creation.

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE dbo.CreateRenamedTable
AS
BEGIN
IF  EXISTS (SELECT  1  FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'MyTable')
BEGIN
IF  EXISTS (SELECT  1  FROM sys.columns WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyTable') AND name = 'Account_ID_Renamed')
BEGIN
CREATE  TABLE dbo.NewTable
(
Account_ID_Renamed_01 INT  -- New column name
);
INSERT  INTO dbo.NewTable (Account_ID_Renamed_01 
SELECT Account_ID_Renamed 
FROM MyTable;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
THROW 50000, 'Column Account_ID_Renamed does not exist in MyTable.', 1;
END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
THROW 50000, 'Table MyTable does not exist.', 1;
END
END
```

[image]

[image]

[image]